# Log forging except OWASP ESAPI in java

Tags: java

Is there any other way through which we can prevent log forging except ESAPI in java?
I am using Lombok slf4j annotation

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your message with

```
message.replaceAll("\n", "\\n").replaceAll("\r", "\\r")
                    .replaceAll("\t", "\\t");
```